# Between two dates in vba for ms access 2010

Tags: database, ms-access-2010

I have a form with multiple combo boxes that opens a report according to the values in my combo boxes.  This works but I was asked to give an option to the Effective Date field so a date range can be entered.

I added two text boxes (`txtReqCreationStartDate` and `txtReqCreationEndDate`) for beginning and ending.

I tried doing the between...and in the query but then my combo boxes don't work.

I never used SQL but found this online and entered it in the code for the Apply Filter on click button but I get all of the records.  Others have tried to help but I always get all the records.

Here is all of the code for the On Click event.

```
Private Sub cmdVacanciesWithNoRequisitionParameters_Click()
On Error GoTo cmdVacanciesWithNoRequisitionParameters_Click_Err

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qryVacanciesWithNoRequisition WHERE " _
       & "DateValue([Effective Date]) Between #" & Format([txtReqCreationStartDate], "yyyy-mm-dd") & "# And #" & Format([txtReqCreationEndDate], "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#;"

'Person Number
    If Not IsNull(Me.cboPersonNumber) Then
        strFilter = strFilter & " AND [Person Number] Like """ & Me.cboPersonNumber & """ "
    End If

             'Person Name
    If Not IsNull(Me.cboPersonName) Then
        strFilter = strFilter & " AND [Person Name] Like """ & Me.cboPersonName & """ "
    End If

             'Job Code
    If Not IsNull(Me.cboJobCode) Then
        strFilter = strFilter & " AND [Job Code] Like """ & Me.cboJobCode & """ "
    End If

         'Person Number
    If Not IsNull(Me.cboBusinessUnit) Then
        strFilter = strFilter & " AND [Business Unit] Like """ & Me.cboBusinessUnit & """ "
    End If

         'Department
    If Not IsNull(Me.cboDepartment) Then
        strFilter = strFilter & " AND [Department] Like """ & Me.cboDepartment & """ "
    End If

         'Supervisor
    If Not IsNull(Me.cboSupervisor) Then
        strFilter = strFilter & " AND [Supervisor] Like """ & Me.cboSupervisor & """ "
    End If

         'Job Title
    If Not IsNull(Me.cboJobTitle) Then
        strFilter = strFilter & " AND [Job Title] Like """ & Me.cboJobTitle & """ "
    End If

            'If the report is closed, open the report
    If SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, acReport, "rptVacanciesWithNoRequisition") <> acObjStateOpen Then
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptVacanciesWithNoRequisition", acPreview, qryVacanciesWithNoRequisition
    End If

        'if report was open, use filter
    With Reports![rptVacanciesWithNoRequisition]
        .Filter = Mid(strFilter, 6)
        .FilterOn = True
    End With

cmdVacanciesWithNoRequisitionParameters_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

cmdVacanciesWithNoRequisitionParameters_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume cmdVacanciesWithNoRequisitionParameters_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: *(You need to clean up your formatting a little bit more, please. Not all of the `sub` appears as "code.") ### That being said, I would suggest that you `Debug.print` the `strFilter` after you have completely generated it, so that you can *see* what the finished string contains. ## Also, exactly why do you use `Mid(strFilter, 6)`? ## If you're "getting all the records," there must be something wrong with your filter. Keep workin' it ... you *should be* basically on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

It should work for you - you just did a copy/paste without using the same variable name as your filter uses.

**Change**

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qryVacanciesWithNoRequisition WHERE " _
       & "DateValue([Effective Date]) Between #" & Format(Me.txtReqCreationStartDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "# And #" & Format(Me.txtReqCreationEndDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#;"
```

> **EDIT - knowing now that Effective Date is a text field**

**Change it to:**

```
If (IsDate(Me.txtReqCreationStartDate) AND  IsDate(Me.txtReqCreationEndDate)) then
        strFilter = strFilter & " CDate([Effective Date]) Between #" &   
    CDate(Me.txtReqCreationStartDate) & "# And #" & _  
    CDate(Me.txtReqCreationEndDate) & "#"
End If
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help.  I like the one with Null because I knew I had to check for that.  I tried both of them but received "Undefined function 'Value' in expression both times.  It doesn't seem to like the word Value from DateValue.

Comment: Sorry I assumed you had already checked your SQL - If EffectiveDate field is a date field you can just remove that DateValue - I didn't even check to see if that was a real function or not. Updated by answer

Comment: [Effective Date] is a text data type.  The data in the table shows as yyyy-mm-dd .

Comment: Okay - edited my answer to fit your field type. You might not even need the "#" when using CDate, but that I haven't tested

Comment: I got it to work.  This is what I needed to be part of my code.  It will also work in combination with the other combo boxes I have.

    If Not IsNull(txtReqCreationStartDate) And Not IsNull(txtReqCreationEndDate) Then
        strFilter = strFilter & " AND [Effective Date] Between """ & Me.txtReqCreationStartDate & """ And """ & Me.txtReqCreationEndDate & """"
    End If